# Wrong charset encoding using openshift

Tags: spring, maven, utf-8, character-encoding, openshift

I'm trying to deploy my web app with service openshift. I set charset encoding on very jsp like that: `<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java"%>`
in controllers i have: `produces = "text/html;charset=UTF-8"`
and my pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <finalName>TrunkSchedule</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <!--some dependencies-->
</dependencies>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>openshift</id>
        <build>
            <finalName>TrunkSchedule</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                        <outputDirectory>deployments</outputDirectory>
                        <warName>ROOT</warName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

locally everything works fine, but when deploying the encoding is broken.
may be the problem in openshift?

Comment: If you have set the properties like `project.build.sourceEncoding` than you can omit the configuration entries `<encoding>..</encoding>` cause those are the default values for both plugins maven-compiler-plugin as well as maven-war-plugin...Furthermore the `src/main/webapp` is the default for maven-war-plugin so no need to configure it...Apart from that what kind of error do you get? log file output?

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks for your advices. 
i have no errors, but all my words are displaying like "?????"

Comment: @andron How did you fix it?